# dont move background while scroll down web page

Tags: language-agnostic

is there a way to dont move background of a webpage while scrolling down?
I dont know how to do it, maybe using PHP, CSS or javascript?

Thbaks

Answer (score 2):

```
body
{
background-image:url('mybackgroundimage.png');
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```